# What can I do to repair a corrupted exFAT filesystem that fsck.exfat doesn't find to be corrupted?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, exfat

I was cleaning free space in an external drive by filling a file with `/dev/zero` until it filled the whole available space. I left a command to delete the file as soon as it finished and left that in background. The commands finished and I kept using the computer until it hanged due to a memory management issue.

After I powered it up again, I found that the device had zero free space left, but the files had been deleted. They were nowhere and, using `testdisk`, I could even see that they appeared as deleted. Yet there was no free space.

I ran `fsck.exfat` (version 1.3.0) with the `-a` option, and it claimed there was no issue.

Note that this is a non-partitioned block device. I just formatted the whole device with exFAT instead of creating a partition table before and formatting a partition. This creates some issues while trying to fix it with other tools.

I tried to open it in Hiren's Boot Mini Windows XP, and none of its tools could recognize it. Somehow, after I rebooted, Ubuntu couldn't recognize it either; it gave a VBR checksum error. This error was identified and quickly fixed by `fsck.exfat`, however, the previous problem remained the same.

I tried creating and deleting a file with the same name to see if it helped, but it didn't. GParted seemingly can't do anything with it either.

Any ideas of what I could do?

Comment: Gparted won't make a new partition table on the device?

Comment: @CharlesGreen If I create a partition talbe on it it will destroy my current filesystem. It is a non-paritioned block device. And Gparted doesn't ask to create a partition table. It recognizes the filesystem just fine, it knows it is a EXFAT filesystem, but it has a red exclamation point and says it can't read the contents. It doesn't explain why it can't tho.

Comment: The quickest pain will be to reformat the partition. If you destroyed the entire drive, then recreate partition table and partition.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? exFAT Ubuntu only works on 20.04 and later.